# Can I put 1.5-inch Schedule 40 pipe inside a 2-inch metal pipe to reline my shallow well?

Tags: plumbing, well, sprinkler-system

I use a shallow well in my backyard to water my lawn. It's about 25 feet deep and has water starting at about 12 - 15 feet yearly. The well pipe is 2" in diameter, and I believe has a leak that causes the system to lose vacuum. After many tests, I've concluded that I need to either sink a new Sandpoint system or see if I can reline the existing pipe with a smaller PVC pipe. Does anyone know if a 1 1/2 inch schedule 40 PVC pipe will fit inside my 2" well pipe?

Comment: what is the wall thickness of the well pipe

Answer (score 2):

OD of 1.5" PVC is 1.9"

Of course you'll need to source a 20 foot stick to avoid needing a fatter coupling in the middle of it. Polyethylene water/well pipe would be a better bet in terms of easy access to continuous lengths over 10 feet. But you might be able to find a 20 foot stick at a good plumbing supply.

ID of 2" schedule 40 steel pipe is 2.067" - Schedule 80 ID is 1.939"

Odds are excellent that due to corrosion, the 1.5" won't fit in your old steel pipe casing anyway, despite the numbers implying that it should (with new, clean pipes - which you won't have)

1-1/4" (OD 1.66") *might* fit if the rust lumps are not too large and firmly attached.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use 1 1/4, and may have to hydro jet the pipe if needed. I'm looking at how that works now.